# How can params be passed through Ionic Modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, parameters

Like we pass params through modal, as did in below by `resolve` example :

```
$scope.someFunction = function(item) {
  item.root = true;
  modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    controller: 'newController',
    templateUrl: '/views/modals/somePage.html',
    resolve: {
      params: function () {
        return { item: item};
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I am not sure how to pass params in ionicModal ??

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('main/templates/viewPage.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.modal = modal;
      });
```

Is there an option along with `animation` as in above ionicModal code?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass any data. Your parent scope is already passed as

```
scope : $scope
```

So you can take your data as `scope.item`.

Please follow this URL
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-from-parent-controller-to-ionicmodal/2030/2

Comment: Thanks. I will check

Comment: Thank you so much.